# UWP : How to dynamically select last typed word in a textbox and change its highlight color?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Here is a winform code that I used to get last typed word

```
string txt = richTextBox1.Text;
string lastWordspace = txt.Substring(txt.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
string lastWord = lastWordspace.Substring(lastWordspace.LastIndexOf("\n") + 1);

richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(lastWord);
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = lastWord.Length;
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightCoral;
```

I want the same functionality in UWP. How can I select the last typed word in a textbox and change its highlight color dynamically using c#?

Answer (score 2):

In UWP, the counterpart to `RichTextBox` is `RichEditBox`.

You can try this:

```cs
TestRichEditBox.TextDocument.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out string txt);
int lastIndex = txt.Length - 2;
TestRichEditBox.Document.Selection.SetRange(lastIndex, lastIndex + 1);
TestRichEditBox.SelectionHighlightColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral);
```

Best regards.